# ISCHANGED or alternative in Apex Class

Tags: apex

I want to replace a workflow rule with a scheduled apex class.

The class needs to evaluate all records where the BMCServiceDesk__incidentResolution__c field has been changed and it's not blank.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The basic pattern is quite simple. If you are looking for a change in trigger records, you can compare it to the old record using `oldMap`. Here is a common approach:

```
for (MyObject__c newRecord : trigger.new)
{
    if (newRecord.SomeField__c != trigger.oldMap.get(newRecord.Id).SomeField__c)
    {
        // field changed
    }
}
```

However, you should strive for logic-less triggers, and also to maintain `Separation Of Concerns`, so I would recommend that you implement the **[Selector](https://github.com/bluewolf-beyond/selector)** library, which makes your filters dead simple to write, abstract out of your action methods, and test.

You can declare each filter in your `Service Layer`, for example:

```
public with sharing class MyObjectService()
{
    public Select.Filter hasSomeFieldChanged()
    {
        return Select.Field.hasChanged(MyObject__c.SomeField__c);
    }
    public static void someAction()
    {
        // separate your filters and actions!
        // it will make each easier to test
    }
}
```

Then in your trigger handler, you just compose the filter and action:

```
MyObjectService.someAction(
    MyObjectService.hasSomeFieldChanged().filter(newRecords, oldMap)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

- Create a field on your object to store the previous value.
- Use a before insert trigger to populate this previous value field with the old value.
- Schedule your class to compare both fields. If they are different then the value was changed.

Answer (score -3):

It is possible only in trigger and not possible in Apex class, but there is workaround,I'm not sure if the solution is feasible or not for your requirement :

You can clone the record before the changes and tally with the updated changes. please find the below code snippet .

```
public with sharing myControllerClass {
    SObject[] oldRecords;
    ApexPages.StandardController con;

    public SObject[] myRecords;

    public myControllerClass(apexpages.standardcontroller controller) {
        // Populate myRecords first
        oldRecords = myRecords.deepClone(true,true,true); // Copy
    }

    public ApexPages.StandardController mySave() {
    update myRecords;
        for(Integer i = 0;i < myRecords.size();i++){
        if(myRecords[i].myField__c != oldRecords[i].myField__c)
            { do something }
        }
    }      
}
```

i think it will solve the purpose.